# What should be the value to set for the Content-Type in this situation?

Tags: php, web-services, character-encoding, content-type

I want to create a `PHP` `webservice` : there are only `functions` which return values from a MySQL database column values within this PHP file , there is no `html` `tag`. So what should be the value to set with the Content-Type in this code : `header('Content-Type: xxx; charset=UTF-8');` ?

Comment: What content does your service respond with?

Comment: The service should return a String.

Comment: set text/html. this will take your return data

Comment: I set it to text/html but I had issue with accentuated letters : the webservice throws exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `text/plain` if it's plain text
- `text/csv` if it's in CSV format
- `application/json` if it's JSON
- `application/xml` if it's XML

For a "web service", you should look into using one of the latter two.

Comment: My real problem is when the column value contains accentuated letters : the webservice doesn't support !

Comment: You'll need to give way more context to be able to answer this. Which webservice are you talking about? Is that *your server script*? What is the complete error message? Please update your question with this information.

Comment: I have already created a question about it in this link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-services?sort=featured&pagesize=15[link]

Comment: Pardon me for not searching for other questions. *This* question is about the output of your PHP server though, right? What exactly are you outputting? What encoding is it in? Are you sure it's UTF-8 encoded? How are you fetching and outputting the data? Try to confirm one thing at a time, we don't care about the Java client in this question. Maybe you should read this: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: I found the answer : I passed the `PHP` function `mb_convert_encoding` to the column value and it works ! The accentuated letters issue is resolved ! Thanks !

Comment: I would humbly suggest that there's another root issue with encodings here which you should fix instead of converting the encoding. But whatever works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type: text/plain should do.

Comment: There is an issue when column values contain accentuated letters : the webservice throws an exception , something like XMLPullException or something like that :)